# state variable has wrong value in functional component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-functional-component

Im trying to add and remove input box in a form. I will controll this box with useState hook. I dont have any problem with add in state variable but when I want to remove from state variable, state variable has wrong value.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
export default function Addable() {
  const [element, setElement] = useState([]);
  function add() {
    const list = [...element];
    const length = element.length;
    list.push(
      <React.Fragment>
        <input key={length} />
        <button onClick={()=>{_delete(length)}}>delete</button>
      </React.Fragment>,
    );
    setElement(list);
  }
  function _delete(index) {
    //****element has wrong value here****//
    const list = [...element];
    list.splice(index, 1);
    setElement(list);
  }
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <button onClick={add}>add Element</button>
      {element}
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong; you want to delete only the input box for which delete has been pressed.

Comment: yes. every input has a delete button.@ManuSharma

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The slice function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) won't change `list` array

```js
const animals = ['ant', 'bison', 'camel', 'duck', 'elephant'];
animals.slice(2)
console.log(animals);
```

You might want to use [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) instead, to prevent closure problem, pass a [function to `settlement` to set the state on the current state](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#what-can-i-do-if-my-effect-dependencies-change-too-often)

```
function _delete(index) {
    //****element has wrong value here****//
    console.log(element);
    setElement((currentEl) => {
      const list = [...currentEl];
      list.splice(index, 1);
      return list
    });
  }
```

**NOTE**: If you use an uncontrolled input component, you need to generate a unique id for input and set it as a key. because React will check key to know which element is to be removed. For example, you have element has length 5, then you remove element index `2` so now element has length 4 but index 2 still there, so React doesn't know you delete index 2 (cuz key 2 is still there) so it will shift 3 to 2, 4 to 3.. [Check this for a better explanation and demo](https://medium.com/@robinpokorny/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318)

You need to create a unique id, [uuid as a choice](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid)

```
function add() {
    const list = [...element];
    const length = element.length;
    const uniqueId = uuid()
    list.push(
     {id: uniqueId
      comp: () => (<React.Fragment>
        <input key={uniqueId} />
        // index is length-1
        <button onClick={()=>{_delete(uniqueId)}}>delete</button>
      </React.Fragment>)
     }
    );
    setElement(list);
  }

function _delete(elementId) {
   // Because we set new state on current state
   // it's better to pass an function into setElement like this to prevent some problem with closure
   setElement(currently =>{
      return currently.filter(el => el.id !== elementId );
    });
}
return (
  <React.Fragment>
    <button onClick={add}>add Element</button>
    {element.map(el => el.comp())}
  </React.Fragment>
);
```

[image: Edit hidden-currying-hmh4m]

Comment: even if you use splice it is n't working just try the same code in sandbox and try adding 4 buttons and delete 1st one...it is deleting all

Comment: One more thing needs to be changed is `length` to `length -1`, could you provide the codesandbox?

Comment: @ManuSharma Could you please provide a codesanbox, and as I mentioned in note in this case you **NEED TO** generate a unique id for rather than using index.

Comment: @TonyNguyen yeah I agree that can work. Haven't tried it tho. Here is the sandbox for you to implement what you suggested. [codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-sound-4qmk1?file=/src/Demo.js)

Comment: @ManuSharma I have added a codesandbox you can try it

Comment: thanks for your response. but my problem is not about array.when _delete function was called, state variable had not correct length and values.also I generete id for inputs

Comment: @Lhe what was wrong with your state, could you provide expected results and the result you actually got. It's better to provide a codesandbox for it.

Comment: try  to add some input fields.then delete one of input and see console log .  https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-bhabha-pcdmy?file=/src/App.js @TonyNguyen

Comment: @Lhe that is the problem of closure, I updated my answer, please have look again, and this one is a closest version to your code and it works as expected: https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-wilbur-mjt4y